# How to integrate your own application inside wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication, integration

I am developing a small app and I wish to use the wordpress user roles and capabilities and authentication system.

The problem is that I don't know wich file I do need include in order to use the wp session and features and where I need to place my files.

Do I need to put files in root or in theme?
Do I need to develop it as a plugin?

Cheers
JW

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys it seems I have solved just adding the wp-load.php in my external file.
cheers